# How to enable Symfony Profiler toolbar only for local environment?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I'm new to using Symfony so not quite sure how to go about doing this. I'm using a local environment to develop a Symfony site. We have production and development sites set up as cloud environments. I'd like to enable the Symfony Profiler toolbar for my local environment *only* (it's disabled in development, and production of course). Currently the only way I see to do it is edit the `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml` file, but undo the change before I push my code.

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```

This is a pretty manual process—is there any way to override the settings in the `web_profiler.yaml` file locally, in the `.env.local` file or elsewhere, so that the Profiler toolbar always shows in my local environment?

Comment: So your local environment is not development environment? Why is profiler disabled on your development environment? That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it via `.env.local` like so

```
# .env.local
TOOLBAR=true

# web_profiler.yaml
web_profiler:
  toolbar: '%env(TOOLBAR)%'
```

But don't forget to do `TOOLBAR=false` on the server